# Socket.io 0.7 can not call broadcast.send?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

in socket.io 0.6, i have following example code:

```
var io = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io');
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
      var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
      switch( path ){
           ....
           //core codes
           socket.broadcast(data);
      }
}).listen(8080);

// ... ...

var socket = io.listen(server);
```

and everything going ok.

But now i have renew the socket.io to 0.7 and have changed the socket.broadcast to socket.sockets.broadcast.send(data) ;

Got an exception : can not call send of 'undefined'?

Who can tell me how can i send data to everybody without listening on a certain event?

Maybe here is a way:

```
clients = new Array();
socket.on('connection',function(socket){ clients.push(socket);}
// ...
for(s in clients) s.send(data);
// ...
```

does it really needed to do like this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a sidenote: dont use for(in) to iterate over arrays, use for(;;) instead.

Comment: Yes, i do ! but what else idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In socket.io 0.7 you do:

```
io.sockets.send() // broadcasts to all connected users
io.sockets.json.send() // broadcasts JSON to all connected users
io.sockets.emit('eventname') // broadcasts and emit
```

or to namespaces

```
io.of('/namespace').send('msg'); // broadcast to all connect users in /namespace
```

Comment: Because the broadcast method does not exist on `io.sockets` or `io.of('/namespace')` and we wanted to make a clear distinction between a `socket.broadcast` (which broadcasts to all connected sockets, except! the current socket) and `io.socket.send` which sends it to all users, without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('user connected');
});
```

Comment: I dont think his is the correct way. It should be ``io.on('connection')`` (or ``socket.on`` or ``sioServer.on`` or whatever the returned value of ``require('socket.io').listen`` is called).

Comment: the code snippet is from the socket.io website - it's definitely right.

Comment: Yeah, I got confused with when using namespaces, since the syntax differs a bit then. Sry!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sioServer.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.broadcast.send('Hello, Everybody else!');
});
```

to broadcast to every other connected client (that is except the broadcasting `client` himself) and use

```
sioServer.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    sioServer.sockets.send('Hello, Everybody!');
});
```

to broadcast to everybody (including `client` himself).

Comment: No, i do not want listen on event! the message was posted from curl by php and directly send to each client only!

Comment: The second example will also work from inside an Express/Connect path or basicly anywhere else in your code.