# Trigger a nodeJS socket.io server to broadcast via port 80

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

Realtime Update Mechanism : user writes -> php save it in mysql db -> php send info to nodeJS -> nodeJS send the change all subscribers -> others can notice it in realtime.

The Socket.io server works well and runs on port 8080. I have node http server running on port 80. How can I get a trigger message on the http server and send the message to all socket.io clients?

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Message Broadcast\n');
  console.log("Message Sent");

  //DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK, error
  io.broadcast("Messages");

  //No error but no messages
  io.emit("Message");

}).listen(80, "0.0.0.0");


/**
Other socket.io code which works well..
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Socket.IO 0.7 you should use the following instead to send to all connected sockets without a specific socket reference:

`io.sockets.send("Messages")`

Note that this is different to `broadcast` since that would send to all sockets *except* the socket that initiated the connection - of course you require a sending socket reference which is why your current code wouldn't suffice.

Quote from the wiki page: [Socket.IO/Wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Migrating-0.6-to-0.7+)

> If you want to send a message to everyone you can reference `io.sockets`:
>
> `io.sockets.send('message');`
>
> `io.sockets.emit('event');`

Comment: Thanks! Also for people interested, checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993725/socket-io-0-7-can-not-call-broadcast-send/7002545#7002545

Comment: np! Check out the wiki link for other changes too.